# How can I access style properties on javascript objects which are using external style sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an external style sheet with this in it:

```
.box {
padding-left:30px;
background-color: #BBFF88;
border-width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 400px;
height: 150px;
}
```

I then have this:

```
<div id="0" class="box" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px;">
```

When I then try to access the width of the div:

```
alert(document.getElementById("0").style.width);
```

A blank alert box comes up.
How can I access the width property which is defined in my style sheet?

NOTE: The div displays with the correct width.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem and show me a testcase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `window.getComputedStyle` to get that value. I would recommend against using `offsetWidth` or `clientWidth` if you're looking for the CSS value because those return a width which includes padding and other calculations.

Using `getComputedStyle`, your code would be:

```
var e = document.getElementById('0');
var w = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e,null).getPropertyValue("width");
```

The documentation for this is given at MDC : [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:window.getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 2):

offsetWidth displays the actual width of your div:

```
alert(document.getElementById("0").offsetWidth);
```

This width can be different to what you have set in your css, though.
The jQuery way would be (I really don't want to mention them all the time, but that's what all the libraries are there for):

```
$("#0").width(); // should return 400
$("#0").offsetWidth(); // should return 400 as well
$("#0").css("width"); // returns the string 400px
```

Comment: The plain javascript alert doesn't work.
The result is undefined.

Comment: Ups sorry I corrected it. The style didn't belong there of course.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful:

```
        function changecss(theClass,element,value) {
//Last Updated on June 23, 2009
//documentation for this script at
//http://www.shawnolson.net/a/503/altering-css-class-attributes-with-javascript.html
 var cssRules;

 var added = false;
 for (var S = 0; S < document.styleSheets.length; S++){

if (document.styleSheets[S]['rules']) {
  cssRules = 'rules';
 } else if (document.styleSheets[S]['cssRules']) {
  cssRules = 'cssRules';
 } else {
  //no rules found... browser unknown
 }

  for (var R = 0; R < document.styleSheets[S][cssRules].length; R++) {
   if (document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].selectorText == theClass) {
    if(document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].style[element]){
    document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].style[element] = value;
    added=true;
    break;
    }
   }
  }
  if(!added){
  if(document.styleSheets[S].insertRule){
          document.styleSheets[S].insertRule(theClass+' { '+element+': '+value+'; }',document.styleSheets[S][cssRules].length);
        } else if (document.styleSheets[S].addRule) {
            document.styleSheets[S].addRule(theClass,element+': '+value+';');
        }
  }
 }
}
```

It is taken from [here](http://www.shawnolson.net/scripts/public_smo_scripts.js).

Answer (score 0):

The answers are mostly correct, but will do your head in when you try to use them as they depend on the rendering mode of the browser (aka strict/quirks mode, browser vender, etc) - the last answer is the best... use jquery.