# why do I need to set style in js initially rather than use existing style?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning how to drag-and-drop-move DIV's around the document in javascript.  Here is a live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/BBANc/

This works fine in Firefox and I'm not currently developing with any other browser.  However, if you change `set_coords_in_js` to `false`, the demo fails.

Using Firebug to set some breakpoints, you'll notice that this line fails:

```
var div_left = parseInt( mov_div_1.style.left, 10 );
```

There is no value for `mov_div_1.style.left` at this point.  So javascript has no idea what the existing value is, and sets `div_left` to 'NaN'.  This style *is* set, and appears to be valid in the document, but there is no value in the DOM!

If you set `set_coords_in_js` back to `true`, then the above has a value and everything works perfectly as it should.

Why?

If you want to play with this locally, copy-and-paste this into your local demo file.  To see the values (or lack thereof) in Firebug, set your breakpoint on line **39** or **40** and step through, hovering your mouse over the things in the line.  Make sure you set `set_coords_in_js` to `false` to see the problem.

`drag_move_div.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>drag move div demo</title>

<style type='text/css'>
.movDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top:  80px;
  cursor: move;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 1em;
}
.coordinates_display { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() {
  mov_div_1 = document.getElementById('mov_div_1');
  set_coords_in_js = true;

  function update_coordinates( newX, newY ) {
    document.getElementById('coordinate_x').innerHTML = newX;
    document.getElementById('coordinate_y').innerHTML = newY;
  }

  // why do I need to set these here in javascript when they are set in css?
  if( set_coords_in_js ) {
    mov_div_1.style.left = '80px';
    mov_div_1.style.top  = '80px';
  }

  update_coordinates( mov_div_1.style.left, mov_div_1.style.top );

  mov_div_1.onmousedown = function(e){
    mov_div_1.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    mov_div_1.style.color = 'white';
    var div_left = parseInt( mov_div_1.style.left, 10 );
    var div_top  = parseInt( mov_div_1.style.top,  10 );
    var startX   = e.clientX;
    var startY   = e.clientY;
    mov_div_1.onmousemove = function(e){
      var newX = ( div_left + e.clientX - startX );
      var newY = ( div_top  + e.clientY - startY );
      mov_div_1.style.left = newX + 'px';
      mov_div_1.style.top  = newY + 'px';
      update_coordinates( mov_div_1.style.left, mov_div_1.style.top );
    };
  };

  mov_div_1.onmouseup = function(){
    mov_div_1.onmousemove = null;
    mov_div_1.style.backgroundColor = '';
    mov_div_1.style.color = '';
  };

};
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class='movDiv' id='mov_div_1'>[ Click &amp; Drag Me Around (slowly) ]</div>

<p>Coordinates:
<span id='coordinate_x' class='coordinates_display'></span> x
<span id='coordinate_y' class='coordinates_display'></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057270/how-to-access-css-properties-in-javascript-when-applied-via-external-css-file). When you access `element.style`, you're not accessing the *computed* style (which includes stylesheet declarations), you're accessing the "style" attribute on the element itself. So when you try to get a value from `mov_div_1.style`, no style attribute is available, and it will come back as an empty string.

To fix this, you need to use either `element.currentStyle` (older IE versions, I think) or `element.getComputedStyle()` (modern browsers):

```
var computedStyle = mov_div_1.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(mov_div_1);
var div_left = parseInt( computedStyle.left, 10 );
var div_top  = parseInt( computedStyle.top,  10 );
```

[See the working jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Dj3h2/)