# How to read a CSS value from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, element

I was wondering how you could read and save to a variable the CSS value of a HTML element. For example say you have this:

```
<tr id="presentationProperty" style="display: none;">
```

I would want to be able to read the display: none property and save it to a variable inside JavaScript. Is this possible and if so, *how*?

Comment: Do not post such easy question on SO. Use Google!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access style properties on javascript objects which are using external style sheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193409/how-can-i-access-style-properties-on-javascript-objects-which-are-using-external)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
var display = document.getElementById('presentationProperty').style.display;
```

Globally, you can access to styles properties of an element like this:

```
var getStyle = function(elementID, prop) {
  return document.getElementById(''+elementID+'').style[prop];
};

alert (getStyle('presentationProperty', 'display')); // block
alert (getStyle('presentationProperty', 'position'));
alert (getStyle('presentationProperty', 'backgroundColor'));
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get the element, and then you can use the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style):

```
var element = document.getElementById("presentationProperty");
var display = element.style.display;
```

[See here for a full list](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ElementCSSInlineStyle) of available style properties

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the final style applied to an element, use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle). This includes any style applied to the element, whether it is an external stylesheets, styles defined within the same document, element styles or styles applied by JavaScript.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("presentationProperty");
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("display");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('presentationProperty').style.display;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getComputedStyle()` to get applied css value on particular element, something like this.

**HTML**

```
<tr id="presentationProperty" style="display: none;">
```

**javaScript**

```
var tr= document.getElementById('presentationProperty');
var computedStyle = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(tr);
var dispVal = computedStyle['display']
```

This would more usefule when you appied the css(`display`) as external or internal css.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('presentationProperty');
console.log(el.style.display);
```

It however will return empty string if the element has no display property defined inside css (i.e. it is inheriting default display property).

Answer (score -1):

Try This for getting all properties:

```
var css = document.getElementById('presentationProperty').style.cssText;
alert(css);
```